# Celery logs on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, celery

I deployed a Celery app on Heroku, but I don't see any task related information in Heroku log (I know that tasks are actually executed). As far as I know Heroku automatically collects everything that was logged to stdout or stderr. Does Celery not log to stdout/stderr by default? Or do I need need to implement custom logging? I would expect to at least see something like "executing task X" in the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your celery workers are issuing print statements or using the standard python logging classes, then you should see something that looks like this in your heroku logs:

> 2015-04-25T00:25:00.072929+00:00 app[celeryd.1]: [2015-04-25
>   00:25:00,072: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task contest-winner
>   (app.contest_win)

celeryd will be replaced by whatever you named the celery worker in your ProcFile.  Mine looks like this and you can see the process label in the logging statement above:

```
celeryd: celery -A app.celery worker -E -B --loglevel=INFO
```

Of course, you have to set the log level too :).

Comment: Ah, I was missing `--loglevel=INFO`. Thanks!